# Why is my laravel policy authorization not working after a while

Tags: laravel, authorization, policies

I'm following the laracasts 5.7 series and I was working on the authorization part using policies. It was working fine when I first added it. But the next day when I opened the app again (without TOUCHING any of the code) I kept being thrown to a 403 error. This happened the two times already. At first I just thought I messed up the code. So I redid the whole policy authorization again. But the second time, I made sure everything was working fine before I saved my code. And then the same thing happened.
Here's my code so far:
ProjectPolicy.php:

```
  public function touch(User $user, Project $project)
{
    return $project->owner_id == $user->id;
}
```

AuthServiceProvider.php:

```
 class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The policy mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $policies = [
        // 'App\Model' => 'App\Policies\ModelPolicy',
          'App/Project' => 'App\Policies\ProjectPolicy',
    ];

    /**
     * Register any authentication / authorization services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();

        //
    }
}
```

web.php:

```
Route::resource('projects', 'ProjectsController')->middleware('can:touch,project');
```

ProjectsController.php:

```
use App\Project;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ProjectsController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct() {
      $this->middleware('auth');
    }
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $projects = Project::where('owner_id', auth()->id())->get();
        return view('projects.index', ['projects' => $projects]);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('projects.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $validated = request()->validate([
          'title' => 'required',
          'description' => ['required','min:5']
        ]);
        $validated['owner_id'] = auth()->id();
        Project::create($validated);
        return redirect('/projects');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(Project $project)
    {

        // $this->authorize('update', $project);
        // abort_if($project->owner_id !== auth()->id(), 403);
        // $this->authorize('touch', $project); // from ProjectPolicy
        // abort_if( \Gate::denies('touch', $project), 403);

        return view('projects.show', ['project' => $project]);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(Project $project)
    {
        return view('projects.edit', ['project' => $project]);
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Project $project)
    {
        $project->update(request(['title','description']));
        return redirect()->action(
          'ProjectsController@show', ['id' => $project->id]
        );
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy(Project $project)
    {
        $project->delete();
        return redirect('/projects');
    }
}
```

To be clear: It was working the night before, and the next day when I opened the app it kept throwing me to a 403 error even when I didn't edit the code at all. I don't know what's happening at all.

Comment: can you do a Log::debug ($user) and Log::debug($project) inside your touch method of your policy and uncomment out the authorization in the controller and see if that is even logging it?

Comment: Have you tried clearing all the cache? php artisan cache:clear & php artisan config:clear & php artisan view:clear? May not be the resolution but I'v lost count how many times this has resolved little bugs I've have.

Comment: @BradGoldsmith Where can I get resuts of the Log::debug($user)? Also I've gotten rid of the middleware in the web.php file. And just used the authorization in the controller. It works fine. Just really curious why it stopped working though.

Comment: @Petay87 Tried it. Didn't work for me :(